# How to get my IHttpNegotiate implementation called by IWebBrowser?

Tags: c++, com, iwebbrowser2

I use [cwebpage_src](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cwebpage.aspx?msg=3595614#xx3595614xx) code and I need to update some HTTP request headers while clicking on links. As I understand it can be done with self implementation of IHttpNegotiate->BeginTransaction. But how to get my IHttpNegotiate implementation called??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although I have no experience of writing one, I believe that you need to write an [asynchronous pluggable protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916.aspx), as recommended in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/87ff3e32-4a19-4e7f-a5d5-1dff082b8d3c).

Details of how and why to do this are scattered around the web in various places, but the best exposition that I've read is in [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.mshtml_hosting/msg/76bf4910a289d4b3?pli=1) by [Igor Tandetnik](https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile=b3eb0170-44f2-4819-b048-8616caa4d107) (abridged here for brevity):

> There are several technology layers
>   that support the download and
>   navigation in Internet Explorer and
>   WebBrowser control. At the top, there
>   is WebBrowser itself and MSHTML object
>   that provides HTML parsing and
>   rendering. The client uses such
>   interfaces as IWebBrowser2 and
>   IHTMLDocument2 to communicate with
>   these high-level objects.
>
> WebBrowser and MSHTML use URL Monikers
>   library to perform actual downloads.
>   URLMon exposes its services via
>   IMoniker and IBinding interfaces, and
>   the client (say MSHTML) implements
>   IBindStatusCallback and a number of
>   associated interfaces, e.g.
>   IHttpNegotiate or IAuthenticate.
>
> Next down is an Asynchronous Pluggable
>   Protocol handler. An APP encapsulates
>   the details of a particular protocol,
>   such as http, file or res.
>
> ...
>
> Most of the time, an application
>   hosting a WebBrowser control (or a BHO
>   running inside IE) uses high-level
>   services provided by WebBrowser and
>   MSHTML objects. However, sometimes
>   these services are insufficient, and a
>   lower-level hook is required.
>
> ...
>
> It would be nice to be able to hook
>   into the communication sequence
>   between WebBrowser/MSHTML and URL
>   Monikers. Unfortunately, there does
>   not seem to be any way to do that - at
>   least, none that I know of. So, we
>   look at the next level - a
>   communication between a URL moniker
>   and an APP.
>
> ...
>
> Now, it is rarely necessary to
>   implement a full-blown APP from
>   scratch - after all, how often do new
>   protocols actually get defined? But
>   for our purposes, it is useful to
>   implement a so-called passthrough APP
>   (pAPP). A pApp is an object that
>   implements both sides of URL
>   moniker-to-APP communication, that is,
>   it implements both IInternetProtocol
>   and IInternetProtocolSink /
>   IInternetBindInfo. We register it as a
>   temporary handler for a standard
>   protocol, such as HTTP. Now whenever
>   an HTTP request needs to be sent, URL
>   moniker will create an instance of our
>   pAPP and ask it to do the job. The
>   pAPP then creates an instance of a
>   standard APP for the protocol in
>   question (I call it a target APP, or
>   tAPP, but be aware that I've invented
>   the terminology myself, it's not
>   widely accepted, suggestions for a
>   better naming convention are welcome)
>   and acts as its client. At this point,
>   our pAPP becomes a proverbial
>   man-in-the-middle. In the simplest
>   case, any method call made by URL
>   Moniker on pAPP is forwarded to tAPP,
>   and any method call made by tAPP on
>   pAPP is forwarded back to URL Moniker.
>   The pAPP gets to observe and, if
>   desired, modify every bit of
>   information relevant to this request
>   passing back and forth between the
>   moniker and the tAPP.

Igor has a couple of sample projects that should help in writing your own `pAPP`:

- [PassthruApp.zip](http://home.roadrunner.com/~itandetnik/PassthruApp.zip)
- [PassthruAppBeta.zip](http://home.roadrunner.com/~itandetnik/PassthruAppBeta.zip)

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems I have to use this PassthruApp as a template and do not use my current pure C code. I cannot implement in C those class hierarchy logic that is implemented in PassthruApp.