# How can I add an extra http header using IHTTPNegotiate?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, delphi-xe4, twebbrowser, urlmon

How can I add an extra header to the request using IHTTPNegotiate? I added the interface but functions `BeginningTransaction & OnResponse` never get called.

```
TNameSpaceHandler = class(TComObject, IInternetProtocol, IHttpNegotiate)  
...
    function BeginningTransaction(szURL, szHeaders: LPCWSTR; dwReserved: DWORD;
        out szAdditionalHeaders: LPWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnResponse(dwResponseCode: DWORD; szResponseHeaders, szRequestHeaders: LPCWSTR;
        out szAdditionalRequestHeaders: LPWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
...
end;
```

Comment: Can you show more code? If you're implementing a [pass-through pluggable protocol handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3711662/1768303) for your URL namespace, there should be a separate object implementing `IInternetProtocolSink` to be passed to the up-stream protocol handler. That's the object that should also be implementing `IServiceProvider` and `IHttpNegotiate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm silently assuming you're intercepting traffic by both implementing `IInternetProcol` **and** the `IInternetProtocolSink` and `IInternetBindInfo` interfaces, and call the original `IInternetProtocol` to have the work done. In that case it's important to know the direction of who calls who.

If the original handler want the additional headers, it will first cast your `IInternetProtocolSink` into a `IServiceProvider` interface (with `QueryInterface`), and call `QueryService` for an `IHttpNegotiate` instance. By convenience you can add the current object instance and also implement `IHttpNegotiate` on the same object, but this is not required.

When the `BeginTransaction` method of your `IHttpNegotiate` gets called, get a `IHttpNegotiate` instance on the `ProtSink` of the Start call, call `BeginTransaction` and add your header(s) before passing them to the caller.

Comment: I don't think this will add a header to the request.

Comment: This will only get request headers. But it will not add an additional header.

Comment: Read the last paragraph again. Closely.

Comment: I have tried what you said but it will not work. It needs an actual code example. By the way have you tested this before? Could you add extra headers?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: do you want an extra header to arrive into the browser, or do you want an extra header on the outgoing request to the webserver?

Comment: Yes an extra header before it sends a HTTP request to the Webserver. Which is what `IHttpNegotiate::BeginningTransaction` does.

Comment: how would I send an extra header to the browser